# how do i complete this test in Jmeter

Tags: php, apache, jmeter

Here is the test Procedure what i want:
      first,requste this url:

```
  http://servername/request?rt=xml&c=12&s=skxil
```

and it will respnse a xml data like this:

```
          <request type="text">
             <impressionurl>
                   <![CDATA[
                      http://servername/mdtrack?rh=d25904aaaf6e1c353d57016023f8bf4c]]>
             </impressionurl>
          </request>
```

so i resolve this data and get impressionurl is

```
  http://servername/mdtrack?rh=d25904aaaf6e1c353d57016023f8bf4c
```

second, i request this impressionurl：

```
http://servername/mdtrack?rh=d25904aaaf6e1c353d57016023f8bf4c
```

but how can i use Jmeter complete this test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following:

1. Execute first request to `http://servername/request?rt=xml&c=12&s=skxil`
2. Add [Regular Expression Extractor Post Processor](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm) to extract data to JMeter Variable
3. Use JMeter variable as a parameter for next request

Example configuration:

**Regular Expression Extractor**

- Reference Name - anything meaningful, i.e. `rh`
- Regular Expression - in your case it'll be something like `rh=(.+?)]]`
- Template - `$1$`

Remaining fields can be left blank.

**Second HTTP Request Sampler**

- Server Name or IP - `http://servername`
- Path - `/mdtrack`
- Parameter name - `rh`
- Parameter value - `${rh}`

Last 2 parameters should go to "Send Parameters With The Request" section

Some useful links:

1. You can test your Regular Expressions using [Jakarta ORO Demonstration](http://jakarta.apache.org/oro/demo.html) applet
2. You can use combination of [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) to see JMeter Variables values
3. See [JMeter Manual on Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) on how to create regex